# Building a program that puts 10 integers in an array and recognizes the numbers that are repeated and outputs them with their position numbers where

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have to only use the internal linear search algorithm, which is this:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
    for (j = i + 1; j <= 9; j++)
    if (array [i] == array [j])
```

and with given algorithm, I'm a bit stuck here and I built this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    int i , j;
    int array [10];
    std::cout << "Please Enter 10 integers: \n" << std::endl;
    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        std::cin >> array [i];
        for (i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j <= 9; j++)
        if (array [i] == array [j])
            std::cout << array [i] << " is repeated in position numbers: " << i << " & " << j << "\n" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

it works fine for the numbers that are repeated twice or once, I need to improve to work fine for more repeating times, any ideas?

Comment: **1.** This appears to be off-topic on Programmers SE. I'd say it would be a better fit for Stack Overflow (or perhaps Code Review SE, but I'm not sure). **2.** Is the part of your question before the second code block even relevant to the question? I'd say no. Your question is not about being stuck with the first piece of code, but about making the number of iterations/repetitions in the second code block variable. Remove *everything* from your question that is not relevant to that problem. **3.** Please give your question a title that represents your problem, not your program's goal.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is not my language of daily use, but here is the Idea how I would implement it.

I would use a `map<int, List<int>>` Which stores as key the values you have seen so far and as values lists of positions where you have seen them.

You can simply iterate in **O(n)** your input and fill up the map.
On the fly or at the end as a separate step you can read the map and output the numbers and positions of all numbers that have a list of size >=2 in the map.